# Laravel sub-relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following models:

```
class Recipe extends Model
{

    public function parts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RecipePart');
    }
}

class Ingredient extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
            'name','image'
        ];
}

class RecipePart extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RecipePartIngredient');
    }
}
```

In my controller, I want to return a recipe with all recipe parts belongs to him, and all ingredients belong to each recipe part. The following code works, but...:

```
return Recipe::with('parts.ingredients')
            ->where('id',$request->id)->first();
```

It works, my `parts.ingredients` returns the data in my `recipe_part_ingredients` table, which is OK, but I want for each ingredient_id - return the ingredient information from my `ingredients` table. (name, image).

Any idea how I can do this? I tried to add the following code to my RecipePartIngredient, but no luck:

```
public function ingredient() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Ingredient');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

[belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method like That:

```
public function ingredient() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ingredient');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
return Recipe::with('parts.ingredients')
    ->with('parts.ingredients.ingredient')
    ->find($request->id);
```